# Ruby convert integer to hours and minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to convert an integer to hours and minutes in Ruby but am having a brain freeze. I have an integer field called duration, which is set when a form is populated from hours and minutes fields on the form. This but works nicely. What Im struggling with is going the other way. I need to take a @duration in the form of an integer, and populate the form fields when editing a record.

so on the form I am doing this

```
= select_tag "hours", options_for_select((0..12).step(1)), :prompt => "hours", :include_blank => "#{@hours}",  required: true
```

The hours in this example is coming from the controller, which does

```
@hours = (@log.duration / 60).to_i
```

My minutes field on the form is this...

```
= select_tag "minutes", options_for_select((0..60).step(1)), :prompt => "Minutes", :include_blank => "#{@minutes}",  required: true
```

and here is where I am struggling. I need to generate the @minutes variable in the controller, but can't think my way through how to get to it. I guess what I need to do is know the remainder left over when the @log.duration is divided by 60, but how would I get to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The answer was the modulo operator

```
@minutes = (@log.duration % 60).to_i
```

Simple and does the job perfectly. Sorry for wasting your time.

G

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Go ahead and accept your answer, so the question doesn't come up as still unanswered.